# Problema en Php --Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '='

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

Estoy intentando hacer un formulario que me coja los datos de una tabla en phpmyadmin. Me da errror en el código siguiente. Alguien sabe el error?

```
<?php
    if(isset($_GET["libro"])){
        $resultado = mysqli_query($enlaceBD, "SELECT * FROM libros where id= row[$id]");  
    } else {
        resultado = mysqli_query ($enlaceBD, "SELECT * FROM libros where id = '1'"];
    }
    $row = $resultado ->fetch_assoc();
{
```

Comment: probaste con like en vez de =

Comment: id=". row[$id] .")"; estás poniendo el valor como un literal

Comment: `resultado = mysqli_query ($enlaceBD, "SELECT * FROM libros where id = '1'"];` debería ser `$resultado = mysqli_query ($enlaceBD, "SELECT * FROM libros where id = '1'");`

Comment: Como ya se ha indicado, la segunda consulta termina mal, por un `]`, cuando deberías cerrarla con `)`, pero creo que esto también te dará problemas: `... where id= row[$id]` ¿qué es `row` realmente? ¿existe en tu contexto una variable `$id`? También, los valores numéricos conviene ponerlos sin comillas simples: `where id = 1`, a no ser que `id` sea del tipo `VARCHAR`

Answer (score 0):

Reemplaza esto

```
$resultado = mysqli_query($enlaceBD, "SELECT * FROM libros where id= row[$id]");
```

Por esto

```
$resultado = mysqli_query($enlaceBD, "SELECT * FROM libros where id= ".row[$id].")";
```

Comment: también debes recordar que solo poner código sin explicarlo, se considera de baja calidad puesto que la explicación debe existir para que sea comprensible para todos y todas quienes consulten